# How can I get other http.get response inside in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I have this HTML http://pastebin.com/DegTb0iH

has a ng-repeat rulling in rullings within it need to do the vote count of each staff, get these values as follows: http://pastebin.com/EB4KigwS

the problem is there on the lines 17,18 and 19 HTML, totalVotes always returns 0 in JS (or only the last result), if you do the console.log in the success comes the correct result of each type of vote

Can anyone give me a help?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function three times using a different value for `voto_type` (fair enough) but all three of these, on the success callback, will store the result in `$scope.totalVotes` which means they will always display the same and last result.

You need to store each result into a separate $scope variable.

E.g. JS:

```
if (angular.isUndefined($scope.totalVotes)) {
    $scope.totalVotes = {};
}
if (result.total > 0) {
    $scope.totalVotes[voto_type] = result.total;
} else {
    $scope.totalVotes[voto_type] = 0;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<p ng-init="getTotalVotes(rulling.id, 's')">Positivos: {{totalVotes['s']}}</p>
<p ng-init="getTotalVotes(rulling.id, 'n')">Negativos: {{totalVotes['n']}}</p>
<p ng-init="getTotalVotes(rulling.id, 'a')">Abstenções: {{totalVotes['a']}}</p>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help,
but, in ng-repeat I've 2 results for rulling, in both case the totalVotes is the same. How can I get unique result for each rulling.id?

Comment: I resolved using
$scope.totalVotes[rullingId + voto_type] = result.total;

and in the HTML
{{totalVotes[rulling.id + 's']}}